# preg_match with Zend_Mail_Part->getContent()

Tags: regex, preg-match, zend-mail

The following sample code works as expected (it reaches the if-block, does not go in the else-block):

```
// In the real code, $content is a result of Zend_Mail_Part->getContent() (this method returns a string). 
$content = ' ----boundary_2_1dca5b3b-499e-4109-b074-d8b5f914404a Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=abc.pdf Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 JVBERi0xLjINJeLjz9MNCjIgMCBvYmo8PD4+DWVuZG9iag0zIDAgb2JqPDwvUG';

// NOTE: the regex has a trailing space
// name *?= *?"?(?<filename>.*?)"? 
if (preg_match('/name *?= *?"?(?P<filename>.*?)"? /i', $content, $matches))
{
    echo ('file name: ' . $matches['filename']);
}
else
{
    echo('<br>$content:<br/>');
    var_dump($content);

    echo('<br>preg_match result:<br/>');
    var_dump(preg_match('/name *?= *?"?(?P<filename>.*?)"? /i', $content, $matches));

    echo('<br>$matches:<br/>');
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

However, when `$content` is assigned the resulting value of `Zend_Mail_Part->getContent()`, the execution of the code reaches the `else` block. It shouldn't be reaching the `else` block. **Any ideas what might be wrong?**

Comment: Without a string that is a sample of what is returned by Zend_Mail_Part->getContent() it's hard to help you.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. I may be going over the backtrack limit. See: http://nz.php.net/pcre.configuration#ini.pcre.backtrack-limit. Testing the theory.

Comment: Sorry for you but now you should show the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use the free spacing flag:

```
'/name *?= *?"?(?P<filename>.*?)"? /ix'
```

(Add the `x`)